# 21.10: switch between 3 and 4 finger swipe to change workspace

Tags: workspaces, workspace-switcher, 21.10, gestures

In 20.04 in Gnome desktop on Wayland I can swipe with four fingers to initiate a switch between workspaces, but in 21.10 I have to use three fingers.

Is there a way to choose between a 3 or 4 finger swipe for this action in 21.10? I find a three finger swipe a needless inconsistency with the other OSes on the same machine, which all use 4 fingers.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks! Removed that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An insightful individual has solved this problem with a Gnome extension: https://github.com/icedman/swap-finger-gestures-3-4

---

Gnome: push key features to third party extensions depending on fragile internal APIs, ensuring that the features you rely on break regularly. Regressions on every version upgrade!

I wonder why people don't like upgrading...